# Export a class from a module where each instance has a private closure, but it's prototype chain can still be extended?

Tags: javascript, class, closures, ecmascript-6

f.e. suppose I have

```
function foo() {
  var privateVariable = "foo"
  return class Foo {
    constructor() {
      // do something with privateVariable
    }
  }
}
export default foo
```

So I'd be exporting the function that returns a class, then each instance of the class would have a closure from when the function was called to get the class. I could then do

```
import foo from "Foo"
var instance = new (foo())()
```

each instance is made from a returned class, so each instance's prototype has a private closure (yeah, it's not the most efficient since a new class definition is returned each time). The problem is that extending the class means that each instance extended from Foo will share a single closure, f.e.

```
var Foo = foo() // get a new class definition
class Bar extends Foo {
  // ...
}
```

Now each time I make a `new Bar()` then it's prototype will be Foo, but each class extending Foo prototype will share the same private closure (basically the private variables are now *static*) since a new Foo definition isn't being gotten each time.

How would I make Foo extendable so that each `new Bar()`'s Foo prototype has a private closure?

**EDIT Feb 7th 2015 12:53am:** Interestingly, I came up with my own solution, which happens to be similar to the accepted answer of using a WeakMap, except it's just a map, not weak:

```
//
// --- PrivateManager.js
//
function PrivateManager() { // singleton
    this.instances = []
    this.instanceData = {}
    this.currentId = 0
}
PrivateManager.prototype.__register = function(instance, instanceDatum) {
    if (this.instances.indexOf(instance) === -1) {
        this.instances[this.currentId] = instance
        this.instanceData[this.currentId] = instanceDatum
        this.currentId++
    }
}
PrivateManager.prototype.__getMethod = function(desiredMethod) {
    return this[desiredMethod]
}

//
// --- Person.js
//
function PersonPrivateManager() {
    var mngr = this
    this.getName = function() {
        return mngr.instanceData[mngr.instances.indexOf(this)].name
    }
}
PersonPrivateManager.prototype = new PrivateManager()

var privateMngr = new PersonPrivateManager()
function Person(name) {
    privateMngr.__register(this, {
        name: name
    })
}
Person.prototype.getName = privateMngr.__getMethod("getName")

//
// --- app.js
//
var person1 = new Person('Bentra')
console.log(person1.getName()) // Bentra
console.log(person1.name) // undefined

var person2 = new Person('Amadar')
console.log(person2.getName()) // Amadar
console.log(person2.name) // undefined

console.log(person1.getName === person2.getName) // true, references to the same function, no memory waste as far as duplicate functions go.
```

The downside of this is that it's not automatically garbage collected like a WeakMap is. This was an impulse solution; it could be modified to mimic the cleaner API of a WeakMap, minus the garbage collection.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood prototypes. You know that it's not efficient, but why do you insist that each instance has its own class? This does not even have a lot to do with inheritance, just creating `var Foo = foo(), inst1 = new Foo, inst2 = new Foo` is enough to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the same odd thing for your `Bar` classes:

```
import foo from "Foo"
function bar() {
  var Foo = foo();
  return class Bar extends Foo {
    constructor() {
    }
  }
}
export default bar
```

Comment: Aha, thanks!. I forgot that the `extends` part can take an actual expression, that part can also be `return class Bar extends foo() {`.

Comment: Yes, it could be. But seriously, don't use this at all. There hardly ever is a reason to create classes dynamically. I can sense an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The "actual problem" is just "how do I have private variables for each instance of a class, available in the scopes of all the instance's methods?". Doing the way you mention in your answer seems nice because the private variables will be garbage collected, unlike with WeakMap shims, and I've gotta support IE >9.

Comment: You cannot have private variables in prototype methods, by definition. Use symbols, or make your methods privileged (place them and the local variables in the constructor). That's much better than creating one class per instance.

Comment: If I place them in the constructor then each instance will have cloned methods instead of reusing the shared prototype methods. I was aiming to do it without using that extra memory. Can't wait to use weak maps!

Comment: @trusktr: Well, what do you think is the overhead of creating a whole cloned class with all the methods for every instance?! You are no more sharing anything with your factory pattern.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. There's really just no clean solution in ES5 I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Put a [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) into Foo's module top level scope and assign private variables to that weak map with the instance as key.
That way only functions defined in that module will have access to it, making it effectively private.

Comment: Thanks! Coincidentally I came up with a solution that's basically a map, but it doesn't have garbage collection.

Comment: So the "actual problem" is just "how do I have private variables for each instance of a class, available in the scopes of all the instance's methods?"

Comment: I believe WeakMap is the solution when it's supported everywhere, but that isn't the case right now.

Comment: Current chrome, FF, IE, node.js all support it. Which environments don't?

Comment: I've gotta support IE >9.

Comment: Currently 1 out of 10 IE users have IE 9.

Comment: I see. Your question was tagged as ES6, so I assumed you're targeting environments actually supporting ES6

Comment: I think someone else added that tag? Thanks though! WeakMaps indeed will be the exact solution to this when we drop support for IE 9 and 10.